What is the contradiction between being drawn here in Bartle and Sherbert? (Ex. 2.1.17)
Theorem 2.1.9 in Bartle & Sherbert's Introduction to Real Analysis states: If $a \in \mathbb{R}$ is such that $0 \leq a \lt \varepsilon$ for every $\varepsilon > 0$, then $a = 0$.  The theorem is quickly proven by assuming $a>0$ and taking $\varepsilon_0 := a/2$ to obtain $0 \leq \varepsilon_0 \lt a$, a contradiction since $a$ was less than every positive $\varepsilon$.
So far, so good.  Then, exercise (2.1.17) asks:

Prove the following form of Theorem 2.1.9: If $a \in \mathbb{R}$ is such that $0 \leq a \leq \varepsilon$ for every $\varepsilon > 0$, then $a = 0$.

Note the difference here: $a \leq \varepsilon$ instead of $a \lt \varepsilon$.
I was able to find a direct proof. But when grading my own work, I found the following in the solutions manual:


If $a>0$, we can take $\varepsilon_0 := a > 0$ and obtain $0 \lt \varepsilon_0 \leq a$, a contradiction.


I don't see the contradiction. If $\varepsilon_0 = a$, then it is both true that $0 \leq a \leq \varepsilon_0$ and $0 \lt \varepsilon_0 \leq a$. What am I missing?

because then $0<\frac{a}{2}<a$ which is contradiction

I think the solutions manual is missing a factor of $1/2$. As written, there isn’t actually a contradiction yet, but if you set $\varepsilon_0=a/2$, you obtain one.

The notation seems to have changed from $\epsilon$ to $\epsilon_0$ in going from the statement of the exercise to the solutions manual. Are you sure there isn't some hypothesis like $\epsilon<\epsilon_0$ perhaps? That would then give a contradiction
